# Is there any way to read and update data in Firestore using Twilio Functions?

Tags: node.js, database, firebase, twilio, serverless

I am trying to read data from Firestore using the following code. I have added the firebase dependency in the dependencies file. But nothing seems to run except the template code at the end. I have also set the read rules for firestore to true for checking. I'm not even sure if Twilio can be used for this.

```
var firebase = require('firebase');

exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
  
  var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "[API_KEY]",
    authDomain: "[AUTH_DOMAIN]",
    projectId: "[PROJECT_ID]",
    storageBucket: "[STORAGE_BUCKET]",
    messagingSenderId: "[MESSAGING_SENDER_ID]",
    appId: "[APP_ID]"
  };
  
  if (!firebase.apps.length) {
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    console.log('Initialized Firebase app');    
  }else {
    firebase.app();
    console.log('Firebase initialized');
  }
  
try{
  const userRef = firebase.db.collection('users').doc('123');
  const doc = userRef.get();
  if (!doc.exists) {
    console.log('No such document!');
  } else {
    console.log('Document data:', doc.data());
  }
} catch(e) {
  console.log(e);
}

  
  // Here's an example of setting up some TWiML to respond to with this function
    let twiml = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();
  twiml.say('Hello World');
    
  let variable = 'welcome!';

  // You can log with console.log
  console.log('error', variable);

  // This callback is what is returned in response to this function being invoked.
  // It's really important! E.g. you might respond with TWiML here for a voice or SMS response.
  // Or you might return JSON data to a studio flow. Don't forget it!
  return callback(null, twiml);
};
```

[These are the dependencies added to the environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8Wpz.png)

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing seems to run"? 

Also, could you please your dependencies file? You can check the [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) help section to get some hints on minimal reproducible code, unfortunately, your snippet does not contain everything that's needed for someone to reproduce it.

In addition to providing both files, you should provide steps to run it. I'm not familiar with firebase, but I can see that this is a "magic" `handler` export, which should be called by your framework/library.

Comment: By "nothing seems to run", I mean that the `console.log()` statements inside the handler do not log anything to the console. Only the lines at the end, send a response i.e. "Hello World"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I think you have two issues with your code and they are both related to the asynchronous nature of JavaScript.

You are not treating any of the Firebase functions as asynchronous. It turns out that most are synchronous, but when you call `.get` on the `userRef` that is an asynchronous call. Since you are working with `try/catch` we can fix this quickly by defining the whole Twilio Function as an `async` function.

```js
exports.handler = async function(context, event, callback) {
```

You can then use `await` before `userRef.get()` and things should start to work.

```js
  const doc = await userRef.get();
```

The second issue is that you were making that asynchronous call and not waiting for the response before you eventually called `callback`. Once you call the `callback` function the rest of the function execution is terminated. So while that asynchronous call to `userRef.get()` was actually made, it was cancelled once the function reached the `callback` because you weren't waiting for the result.

In both these cases, adding the `async` and `await` should sort out the issue and your function should run as expected.

Here's the whole function with the addition of `async` and `await`:

```js
var firebase = require('firebase');

exports.handler = async function(context, event, callback) {
  
  var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "[API_KEY]",
    authDomain: "[AUTH_DOMAIN]",
    projectId: "[PROJECT_ID]",
    storageBucket: "[STORAGE_BUCKET]",
    messagingSenderId: "[MESSAGING_SENDER_ID]",
    appId: "[APP_ID]"
  };
  
  if (!firebase.apps.length) {
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    console.log('Initialized Firebase app');    
  }else {
    firebase.app();
    console.log('Firebase initialized');
  }
  
try{
  const userRef = firebase.db.collection('users').doc('123');
  const doc = await userRef.get();
  if (!doc.exists) {
    console.log('No such document!');
  } else {
    console.log('Document data:', doc.data());
  }
} catch(e) {
  console.log(e);
}

  
  // Here's an example of setting up some TWiML to respond to with this function
    let twiml = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();
  twiml.say('Hello World');
    
  let variable = 'welcome!';

  // You can log with console.log
  console.log('error', variable);

  // This callback is what is returned in response to this function being invoked.
  // It's really important! E.g. you might respond with TWiML here for a voice or SMS response.
  // Or you might return JSON data to a studio flow. Don't forget it!
  return callback(null, twiml);
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Also, why doesn't the `console.log()` work? Its still not working. I added `twiml.say()` statements right after the log statements and then I was able to see which of the conditionals were being executed. Any idea on how to fix that?

Comment: Where are you looking for the `console.log`s? Are you using Twilio Functions via the UI in the Twilio console or with the Twilio CLI?

Comment: I'm using the Twilio Functions via the UI. I checked the error logs as well as the browser console.

Comment: You need to check live logs are on, under the code area, then you should see them.